# Redrawing to a silverlight canvas every cycle of a loop. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas, draw

any help or pointers would be massively appreciated.

Basically i'm trying to EITHER move OR redraw some ellipses to a canvas once a "turn".

At the moment I can click a button to RenderTransform the ellipse to a new location within the canvas. Whenever I try to do this more than once, for example, incrementing the TranslateTransform X and Y values by one each loop, the whole application hangs. Is this an issues which RenderTransform? The Canvas? The MainPage thread? The code looks solid, so its a mystery as to why it simply wouldnt move the ellipse more than once.

```
private void update()
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        while (turns <= 5)
        {
            TranslateTransform t = new TranslateTransform();
            t.X = x + 1;
            t.Y = y + 1;
            // agent is a child element of a canvas.
            agent.RenderTransform = t;
            turns--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Easier to spot problems when we can see the relevant source-code.

Comment: You're right, here's the update method.

Comment: Why you don't use animations?

Comment: The ellipses are essentially agents that will act according to collision rules and pathfinding, which doesnt work to a storyboard, I just need to update their position every so often.

Comment: Don't underestimate storyboards for simple "move" tasks. You can name any element in a storyboard to get programmatic access to target positions. That way the actual variable frame rate animation is left to the Silverlight engine, instead of you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CompositionTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.aspx) it will help you
look at [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838.aspx)

[another good example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brandf/archive/2007/10/09/fun-with-animation-part-1-compositiontarget-rendering.aspx)

use it like this:

```
private void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Your code here
}
```

and hook the Rendering event `CompositionTarget.Rendering += Update;`

Edit: If you are using Canvas it's better to use Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top attached properties